# Apache embedded Mjpg stream issue

Tags: apache, streaming, debian, raspberry-pi, embed

I am running a mjpg stream through a site hosted by Apache on my Raspberry pi.  If I access the site with embedded stream locally it works as desired.  The problem arises when I attempt to access it through the internet.  The site is accessible but the stream does not show.  I can see the other forms and buttons on the page as well as the frame for the stream but it only has the icon that shows it is unable to load inside (broken image?).  I have tried forwarding several ports from the outside and also configured Apache to host it on ports other than 80.  No mater what port combination I use the result it the same...accessible locally but not fully from the internet.

Right now mjgp is back to broadcasting on port 8080 and is embedded in the site through Apache using the following:

```
<img alt="" src="http://192.168.1.108:8080/?action=stream" width="1280" height="960" />
```

I have tried adjusting the frame rate and resolution etc several times with no success.  I have also tried accessing the page through both Firefox and Chrome with the same results.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue through the use of a php proxy.  I came across a great example on another site that I will post below along with a link to the forum.

```
<?

/*
usage on webpage:
<img src="stream.php">
*/ 
$server = "localhost"; // camera server address
$port = 8443; // camera server port
$url = "/?action=stream"; // image url on server
set_time_limit(0);  
$fp = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
if (!$fp) { 
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";   // error handling
} else { 
    $urlstring = "GET ".$url." HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"; 
    fputs ($fp, $urlstring); 
    while ($str = trim(fgets($fp, 4096))) 
    header($str); 
    fpassthru($fp); 
    fclose($fp); 
} 
?>
```

http://www.plugcomputer.org/plugforum/index.php?topic=6231.0